# How to retrieve all journal events using Akka persistence queries?

Tags: akka, akka-persistence

Akka persistence queries have following predefined operations:

EventsByPersistenceId
EventsByTag
CurrentEventsByPersistenceId
CurrentEventsByTag
AllPersistenceIds

But what if I need to get all past events, some sort of CurrentEvents operation? I can't figure out how I can implement it in Akka persistence queries terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with the persistence queries module, but these operations are all defining some akka-streams sources. You could attempt to combine them as follows:

```
  def currentEvents(fromSequenceNr: Long, toSequenceNr: Long): Source[EventEnvelope, NotUsed] =
    currentPersistenceIds().flatMapConcat(id => currentEventsByPersistenceId(id, fromSequenceNr, toSequenceNr))
```

(`flatMapMerge` with concurrency breadth is an alternative to `flatMapConcat` in case you'd like to parallelise this)

Comment: Thanks. This can be a possibility. I am not sure about efficiency of this method (first getting all persistence ids and then getting events for each of them) vs. getting a snapshot of a live stream. But it doesn't look like there is a method for a snapshot of the whole live stream.